# Pseudoclass :empty not working for email templates

Tags: java, html, css, email, html-email

I am creating email templates and I have a requirement to display a list of roles as follows -

[image]

The list is created using dynamic parameters coming from the backend and not all the roles are being displayed hence I end up having empty bullet points.

```
 <ul>
    <li>::admin_man</li>
    <li>::mem_man</li>
    <li>::term_mem</li>
    <li>::repo_man</li>
    <li>::new_comm</li>
  </ul>
```

I used pseudoclass :empty and even tried using a table with the empty-cell property but nothing seems to work out for outlook-desktop. Any suggestion is appreciated. Please Help!!!

Comment: `:empty` is definitely not universally supported in email clients https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/empty/ can you conditionally render the entire `li`?

Comment: I tried using javascript to append li tag but later found that outlook strips down all the javascript code.

Comment: Are you using any templating language/engine, or just HTML?

Comment: It is plain HTML with inline CSS

Comment: Then it's not really something you can control unless you're fine with partial support for your original approach. Not sure what your configuration is but maybe your backend can replace a single dynamic tag with a `ul` that contains all the parameters that are present as list items or deliver some default value for all line items that are not present. But HTML in emails can't conditionally render in a universal way.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo class `:empty` is not well supported https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/empty/ (HT: [@JHeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7657915/jheth))

It sounds like you need to have each `<li>` element, but have the capacity to add further code (you're not clear though).

To hide content on Outlook/and everywhere, you need to use a few different methods in one hit, like so:

```
<li style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;" hidden>xyz</li>
```

Those email clients that don't support one method (e.g. display:none) will render a tiny invisible bit of text.